# Gradle Multiproject Build pushToLocalMaven before

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project consist of multiple java projects. Let's say we have two projects, ProjectA and ProjectB. I would like to send ProjectA jar to local maven repo, before ProjectB starts to compile. Because ProjectB depends on ProjectA. I know I can do this from command line with `gradle clean build pTML` or `gradle publishToMavenLocal` command separately. But, I want to do this in main build.gradle without any extra steps in one shot.

```
RootProject
├── ProjectA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
└── ProjectB
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding `build.finalizedBy(publishToMavenLocal)` command to all the subprojects. By this way after a project is build, it is directly published to maven local repository. @Vampire thank you for your help, I think also solves the problem but this seems the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the composite build feature where you can replace a binary dependency like `compile 'my.group:project-a:1.0'` by a "sub-build" so that project A is built first and its result being used instead of the declared binary dependency. You can read more about it at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html